# Accessing a WCF Service from a PCL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm trying to call a WCF service from a PCL.

I've found a number of articles and posts detailing this, but they all seem to assume that a `ServiceClient` type object is available to the PCL.  [this](http://mallibone.azurewebsites.net/2014/03/creating-a-asyncawait-wcf-client-proxy-in-a-portable-class-library/) post is an excellent example of that.

Is `ServiceClient` something that should be available to a PCL, or will I need to create one?  I presume if I was creating one then I would been to use the [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) - are there any online resources for this?

(Note: I happen to be using MVVM Cross, but I don't believe this makes a difference to the question)

Answer (score 1):

ServiceClient is something You need to generate with SLSvcUtil or add it with the "**Add Web Reference**" wizard , you don't mention Xamarinin in your question but I give it as granted because you do mention MVVM Cross

go to [**Introduction to Web Services**](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/) and then go straight to **Consuming SOAP Services** and **Consuming WCF Services** sections, ignore all previous article sections, they are rest service related.

even if you are not using Xamarin,the article should steer you into the right direction